# How to convert an SDL1 surface to an opencv Mat

Tags: opencv, sdl

I'm trying to create a opencv `Mat` from an `SDL_Surface` (SDL 1.3).

I've tried various combinations of parameters but I can't get it work.

That's my code:

```
SDL_Surface test_surf = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 16, SDL_SWSURFACE);
Mat testRGB(WIDTH,HEIGHT,CV_8UC3,test_surf->pixels,test_surf->pitch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The bits per pixel didn't match. I changed the bpp of the SDL_Surface from 16 to 24 and now it works.